# I'm trying to perform the Trailhead Mibile SDK trail of creating a hybrid app but I get an error

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android, trailhead

When I run the command cordova build, I am getting an error. I added the versions to the manifest.xml file but that didn't see to have done anything. Can someone assist?

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\System32>CD
>   c:\users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest
>
> c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest>cordova prepare
>
> c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest>cordova build Running
>   command: cmd "/s /c
>   "c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\pl
>   atforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\jenwlee\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8 Running:
>   c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\android\grad
>   lew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\
>   android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true :preBuild
>   :compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE :preDebugBuild :checkDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:compileLint :CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:preBuild
>   :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
>   :CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugJar
>   UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
>   :prepareDebugDependencies :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :processDebugManifest
>   C:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\android\AndroidManife
>   st.xml:25:9 Error:
>           Element activity#com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity at AndroidManifest.x ml:25:9 duplicated with element declared at
>   AndroidManifest.xml:10:9
>   C:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\android\AndroidManife
>   st.xml:0:0 Error:
>           Validation failed, exiting :processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 16.419 secs
>
> c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\android\cordova\node_
>   modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\Tra
>   ilheadHybridTest\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   c:\Users\jenwlee\And
>   roidApps\TrailheadHybridTest\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon= true" ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\jenwlee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
>   cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
>
> c:\Users\jenwlee\AndroidApps\TrailheadHybridTest>